# Get value by supplying key in JSON map variable(in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How to get Value by supplying key to a JSON map variable(in JavaScript)?
I have  `memberIdToNameMap`, which contains  key value pair. I have a `key` using which i want to get the value. How can we retreive it.

I tried  `memberIdToNameMap[key]`,  but its returning `undefined`.

--
Thanks

Comment: This is the correct syntax. We need more code to find the bug.

Comment: Before your call `memberIdToNameMap[key]` type also   `console.log(memberIdToNameMap, key);` to see the current state of your object and the value of `key` variable. This will show that your object currently doesn't have an expected `key`. Obviously you need to debug your code in part of `key` variable initialization or in part of object initialization and/or extending.

Comment: well, when i give  console.log(memberIdToNameMap, key);  it stops at the statement, i.e.,  it doesn't execute the rest code and nothing is displayed FireBug.

Comment: Any errors in console? Is there any if-else or switch operators in your code which can terminate or change an execution flow?

Can you update your question and provide the full code block where this behavior can be reproduced (e.g. make an example at the jsfiddle.net)?